# Do men have more trouble than women pronouncing alveolo-palatals (like ɕ)? Or are there other physiological factors involved?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm curious based on would-be standard samples such as

- provided on Wikipedia;
  compare the same [male] speaker there trying to show the difference between [(alveolo-palatal) ɕ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_sibilant.ogg) and [(palato-alveolar) ʃ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voiceless_palato-alveolar_sibilant.ogg).
- provided on a Polish university page; of the three voices (one male, two female) trying to show the difference between [ɕ (again)](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=5310) but [retroflex non-palatalized ʂ](http://polfon.upol.cz/?sound=4300) (this time)... again I find the male voice (#2) making the least distinction between these.

So I'm curious if these are just my possibly biased observations based on a very limited sample and possibly my "untrained ears", or if there's something more general in this and males indeed have more trouble with alveolo-palatal pronunciation? Are there any surveys of speakers on these putative sex/gender differences with respect to ability to make a clear[er] pronunciation of alveolo-palatal?

Or if this is a bad tack, what are the physiological differences that make the "best", i.e. most clearly distinguishable alveolo-palatal sounds? (Something to do with lower lip or teeth, I might suspect.)

Answer (score 1):

It is just your biases. Wikipedia files are strongly different.
But there are both female voices on a Polish site, that substitute [s̠] and [sʲ] (with more lax, more sibilant pronunciation than a plain [sʲ]) in inlaut and auslaut positions (proşie, wieś) for [ɕ]. So situation is opposite to your vision: not males, but females more often use another allophones for [ɕ]. Today for Polish example only.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about the same site, for *proşie* 1st female (Ola) sounds indeed somewhat towards [ʃ], but the male (2nd voice) seem even more towards [s̠]. I'd rate only the 3rd voice (2nd female Ania) as a clear [ɕ]. For *wieś*, I'd rate the 1st two voices as around [ʃ], again with the male more towards [s̠], only the 3rd voice again as more clear [ɕ].

Comment: Have you any kind of /ɕ/ in your native language!? For me, here only male voice close to any allophonic realisation of it.

Comment: none. I'm taking as yardstick/expectation a couple of YouTube videos on Chinese pronunciation of [ɕ] vs  [s̠], e.g. https://youtu.be/rUlnp0wm5dk?t=73 or 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coTlaHzLWXc The way the guy there pronounces is actually quite what I expect. What's your native tongue, by the way?